# Sturm Liouville regular but strange equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am confronted with the following 2nd order differential equation:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[p(x)\frac{dy}{dx}]+[q(x)+\lambda]y=0
$$
where:
$p(x)=1+x^2$, $q(x)=x$, $-1\le x\le1$.
Clearly a regular S.T. problem.
Tried to look up conventional S.T. problems like Bessel etc - it's not the same. Tried writing $1+x^2=(1+x)^2-2x$, then making change of variables $u=1+x$, but that made it messier. Looking for help. Thanks.
There are also boundary conditions $y(-1)=y'(1)=0$ and we need to find the eigenfunctions $y_\lambda(x)$

Comment: What exactly is the aim of your task?

Comment: I'd like to find the eigenfunctions $y_\lambda(x)$